# Obtener valor de un atributo en JSF <->The class 'xxx' does not have the property 'yyy'

Tags: jsf

Saludos, 
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JSF, en la cual, se despliega un mensaje, el típico "Hola Mundo". Para esto, tengo en un paquete **hola** una clase *Hello*, con la anotación ManagedBean, en la cual defino un atributo *mensaje* y un método para consultar el valor. Hasta ahí nada de problemas. Obtengo el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
<h:head>
        <title>Hola mundo...</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
   #{hello.mensaje}      
</h:body>
```

Pero si en le mismo proyecto creo otro paquete llamado **saludo**, y agrego una clase *Hello*, con la anotación ManagedBean, y un atributo *mensajedos*, cuando intento consultar dicho valor,

```
<h:body>
       #{hello.mensaje}        
       #{hello.mensajedos}        
</h:body>
```

presenta un error, ya que no es posible leer el atributo:

```
The class 'saludo.Hello' does not have the property 'mensaje'.
```

Es entendible, porque no estoy especificando el  paquete. En cierta manera ya esperaba el error. La pregunta es, como hago para especificar el paquete de la clase?

Gracias desde ya

Comment: Tienes dos managed bean con el mismo nombre "hello" y "hello". Si agregas a uno de los MB:  @Named(value = "hello2") y tu html lo actualizas a : #{hello2.mensaje} , deberá funcionar.

Comment: Hola, con  @Named(value = "hello2") no me funciona, se me presenta el mismo error

Comment: Hola, intente de nuevo con tu solución y me funciono. Publícalo como respuesta para marcarla como correcta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos managed bean con el mismo nombre "hello" y "hello". Si agregas a uno de los MB: @Named(value = "hello2") y tu html lo actualizas a : #{hello2.mensaje} , deberá funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Si esta utilizando `CDI` managed beans, hay que asegurarse de asignarle un [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html)  ya que el predeterminado es `@Dependent` y éste no funciona por sí solo.

Hay que asegurarse de tener los setters y getters de las propiedades que está tratando de utilizar por medio de [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) y como es un **bean** quiere decir que hasy que utilizar encapsulamiento, implemementar `Serializable` y tener un constructor vacío.

E.G.:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Hello2 implements Serializable{

   private String saludo = "Saludo 2";

   public void Hello2(){}

   public void setSaludo(String s){
      saludo = s;
   }

   public void getSaludo(){
     return saludo;
   }
}
```

y en el facelet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

      <h:head>
      </h:head>

      <h:body>
          #{hello2.saludo}
      </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aporte. No me soluciono el problema, pero si me sirvió para entender algo que "deduje", respecto a los getter y setter. saludos